# React js: Accessing state of other components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component built using the below code. The aim is to add a class on the card to highlight it when the button inside it is clicked. However, the below code works on the first click but doesn't work for the subsequent clicks. 
I understood that I have to set the clicked state of other elements to false when I remove the class. How can this be done?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './PricingCard.css';

class PricingCard extends Component {

  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      clicked : false
    }
  }

  makeSelection(){

    let elems = document.getElementsByClassName('Card');
    for(var i=0;i<elems.length;i++){
      elems[i].classList.remove("active");
    }
    this.setState({clicked: true});

  }




  render() {

    var activeClass = this.state.clicked ? 'active' : '';

    return (
      <div className= {"categoryItem Card " + this.props.planName + " " +activeClass}>
        <div className="cardDetails">
          <div> {this.props.planName} </div>
          <div className="pricing"> {this.props.price} </div>
          <button onClick={this.makeSelection.bind(this)} className="buttonPrimary"> Select this plan </button>
          <div className="subtitle"> {this.props.footerText} </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default PricingCard;
```

Comment: "The aim is to add a class on the card to highlight it when the button inside it is clicked. However, the below code works on the first click but doesn't work for the subsequent clicks". What you want to happen on next click? toggle the class?

Comment: @Tomasz If I click on an element, a class gets added to that element and the same class gets removed from all the other similar elements. Normal element selection UI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wouldn't it be easier to have the logic in a parent component? Since it is "aware" of all the child Card components.

Have something like...

```
this.state = { selectedComponent: null };

onClick(card_id) {
   this.setState({ selectedComponent: card_id });
}
```

...in render:

```
const cards = smth.map((card) => 
    <Card onClick={this.onClick.bind(this, card.id)} 
        isActive={map.id === this.state.selectedComponent} />
```

Would this work?

Comment: One small issue here is, I cannot directly bind the click function to the component like this. Since the click must be bound to a button inside the component. Any work around for that?

Comment: Maybe pass in the function to the Card component, and bind it inside to a button....   <button onClick={this.props.parentClick}>Click</button>

Answer (score 1):

Best way will be to lift [lift the state up.](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lifting-state-up.html) Like this:

```
class PricingCardContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedCard: NaN,
    }
  }

  handleCardClick(selectedCard){ this.setState({ selectedCard }); }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>{
        this.props.dataArray.map((data, i) => 
          <PricingCard
            key={i} 
            className={this.state.selectedCard === i ? 'active': ''}
            price={data.price}
            onClick={() => this.handleCardClick(i)}
            footerText={data.footerText}
            planName={data.planName}
            plan={data.plan}
          />
        )
      }</div>
    )
  }
}


const PricingCard = ({ className = '', planName, price, onClick, footerText }) => (
  <div className= {`categoryItem Card ${planName} ${className}`}>
    <div className="cardDetails">
      <div> {planName} </div>
      <div className="pricing"> {price} </div>
      <button onClick={onClick} className="buttonPrimary"> Select this plan </button>
      <div className="subtitle"> {footerText} </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);

export default PricingCard;
```

Although it would be better to use some data `id` than index value.